# How do I create an overlapping layout?

Tags: java, android

**How do I overlap Layout like this?**

[image]

Comment: Are you using CardView?

Comment: please share with us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just follow this structure when you overlap the parent view using liner layout need to add minus margin in child view like this.
I have just added the **android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"**

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_150"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/green"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_100"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_20"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_20"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you u achieve it by giving margin top(negative value) to second layout that contain login title.

```
android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
```